# Как в PHP узнать, в каком часовом поясе находится сервер?

Tags: php

Как в PHP узнать, в каком часовом поясе находится сервер?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вас интересует часовой пояс, указанный в **настройках** времени на сервере, то 
[здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) все есть - Смотрите раздел временная зона, ключ "O"

А узнать, где он находится можно у админа:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Установка
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//Считывания вариант 1
if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br         />';
}

//Считывания вариант 2
if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
}
```